# How to set OnClickListener to Expandable RecycleView

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, expandablerecyclerview

I want to set OnClickListeners to the items from my Expandable Recycleview. Each item from the Recycleview should have a button ( like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQWk.jpg : a + button to add tasks and an "x" button for each task to delete it)

I have tried to implement it from some other examples of onClickListeners but nothing worked so far

this is the ADAPTER:

```
public class ExpandableAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<RoutineViewHolder, TaskViewHolder> {
    public ExpandableAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

    @Override
    public RoutineViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_routine, parent, false);
        return new RoutineViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        final Tasks tasks = (Tasks) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.bind(tasks);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(RoutineViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        final Routine routine = (Routine) group;
        holder.bind(routine);

    }
```

RoutineViewHolder:

```
import com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.viewholders.GroupViewHolder;

public class RoutineViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView mTextView;



    public RoutineViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_routine);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void bind(Routine routine){
        mTextView.setText(routine.getTitle());
    }


}
```

TaskViewHolder:

```
public class TaskViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private Boolean checkVal;

    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_task);
        mCheckBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_task_checkbox);
    }

    public void bind(Tasks tasks) {
        mTextView.setText(tasks.name);
        checkVal=((tasks.checkBox==1)?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(checkVal);
    }
}
```

as you can see I have 2 ViewHolders : RoutineViewHolder and TaskViewHolder. I am very confused to where and how I should set the OnClickListener since I want it to behave different for the "Routines" and "Tasks" because they would have different buttons.

"Tasks" should have the + button to add tasks underneath it 
and each task should have an X button to delete that specific task

the expandable recycleview is made out of 2 more of these "Tasks" cathegories.

Comment: Ok both view holders has different responsibilities.
Apply onClickListeners in both.
i.e for + clicklistener will work on + and on X if will work on first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer a solution where I can listen all these callbacks from some higher level (like Activity) where I can change data objects and refresh the RecyclerView keep things in sync based on callbacks. (This is eventually what you will need if you scale this.)

I implemented your code and modified a little to get the expected result.
[image: Sample result]

**For this solution:**

- I created an interface to get callbacks

  - On Add clicked on Routine
  - On Delete clicked on Task
  - On check status changed on Task
- Made my activity to implement that interface and passed it to adapter.
- Adapter passes it to ViewHolder
- ViewHolder will invoke required function upon click.
- In call backs:

  - For ADD: You can know which Routine was clicked
  - For Delete: You can know ParentRoutine, Child Index of Task and Task
  - For Check Change: You can know ParentRoutine, Child Index of Task, Task and New check status.

---

**Code**

### 1. Add new file `ListActionListener.java`

This is the interface.

```java
public interface ListActionListener {
       // Know add was clicked on given routine
       void onAddTaskClicked(Routine routine);
       // Know delete was clicked on given task.
       void onDeleteTaskClicked(Routine routine, Tasks task, int index);
       // Know checkbox clicked on given task (with new checked status)
       void onTaskCheckChanged(Routine routine, Tasks task, int index, boolean checked);
}
```

### 2. Make your activity implement this interface. `ExpandableListActivity.java`

This is my sample activity that you see in the screenshots.

```java
public class ExpandableListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListActionListener{
    ExpandableAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        loadList();
    }

    private void loadList() {
        List<Routine> routines = getDummyRoutineList();
        adapter = new ExpandableAdapter(routines, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private List<Routine> getDummyRoutineList() {
        List<Routine> list = new ArrayList<Routine>();
        Tasks rt1 = new Tasks("R1 Tasks1", 1);
        Tasks rt2 = new Tasks("R1 Tasks2", 0);
        Tasks rt3 = new Tasks("R1 Tasks3", 1);
        Tasks rt4 = new Tasks("R1 Tasks4", 0);
        Tasks rt5 = new Tasks("R1 Tasks5", 0);
        List<Tasks> r1Tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        r1Tasks.add(rt1);
        r1Tasks.add(rt2);
        r1Tasks.add(rt3);
        r1Tasks.add(rt4);
        r1Tasks.add(rt5);
        Routine r1 = new Routine("Routine 1", r1Tasks);


        Tasks r2t1 = new Tasks("R2 Tasks1", 1);
        Tasks r2t2 = new Tasks("R2 Tasks2", 0);
        Tasks r2t3 = new Tasks("R2 Tasks3", 1);
        Tasks r2t4 = new Tasks("R2 Tasks4", 0);
        Tasks r2t5 = new Tasks("R2 Tasks5", 1);
        List<Tasks> r2Tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        r2Tasks.add(r2t1);
        r2Tasks.add(r2t2);
        r2Tasks.add(r2t3);
        r2Tasks.add(r2t4);
        r2Tasks.add(r2t5);
        Routine r2 = new Routine("Routine 2", r2Tasks);

        list.add(r1);
        list.add(r2);
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddTaskClicked(Routine routine) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Add Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteTaskClicked(Routine routine, Tasks task, int index) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Delete Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCheckChanged(Routine routine, Tasks task, int index, boolean checked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On Check changed:"+checked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

### 3. Add "X" button to Task Row layout

This is my sample XML file, your XML may look different. Main thing is to add button for Delete.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="X"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/exp_task_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/exp_task_checkbox"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### 4. Add "+" button to Routine Layout file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="+"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exp_routine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/exp_task_checkbox"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### 5. Update Adapter to accept a ListActionListener

```java
public class ExpandableAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<RoutineViewHolder, TaskViewHolder> {
    ListActionListener listActionListener;
    public ExpandableAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups, ListActionListener listActionListener) {
        super(groups);
        this.listActionListener = listActionListener;
    }

    @Override
    public RoutineViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_routine, parent, false);
        return new RoutineViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(TaskViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        final Tasks tasks = (Tasks) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.bind((Routine)group, childIndex, tasks, listActionListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(RoutineViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        final Routine routine = (Routine) group;
        holder.bind(routine, listActionListener);

    }
}
```

### 6. Update `TaskViewHolder.java`

To accepte listener and invoke callback

```java
public class TaskViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    private Boolean checkVal;
    private Button btnDelete;

    public TaskViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_task);
        mCheckBox=itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_task_checkbox);
        btnDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

    }

    public void bind(final Routine parentRoutine, final int childIndex, final Tasks tasks, final ListActionListener listActionListener) {
        mTextView.setText(tasks.name);
        checkVal=((tasks.checkBox==1)?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(checkVal);
        //add delete button click
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listActionListener.onDeleteTaskClicked(parentRoutine, tasks, childIndex);
            }
        });

        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                //to avoid initial call back
                if(checked != checkVal) {
                    listActionListener.onTaskCheckChanged(parentRoutine, tasks, childIndex, checked);
                    checkVal = checked;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### 7. Update `RoutineViewHolder.java`

To accepte listener and invoke callback.

```java
public class RoutineViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Button btnAdd;

    public RoutineViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exp_routine);
        btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void bind(final Routine routine, final ListActionListener listActionListener) {
        mTextView.setText(routine.getTitle());
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listActionListener.onAddTaskClicked(routine);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Bingo.... Run the code...** :)

Comment: you were overly generous spending your time and sharing your knowledge in such detail! Thank you once again @HBB20

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call setChildClickListener of your ExpandableAdapter object from your activity?

Have a look at this:

```
ExpandableAdapter adapter=new ExpandableAdapter(myExpandableGroupList);
adapter.setChildClickListener(new OnCheckChildClickListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckChildCLick(View v, boolean checked, CheckedExpandableGroup group,int childIndex) {

    }
 });
```

I hope this helps you.